# Create a blank database with Oracle DBCA

Tags: database, oracle, dbca

I use Oracle Database Configuration Assistant to create database. There are 3 default templates:

- General purpose or transaction processing
- Custom database
- Data warehouse

However, choosing any of these 3 template would lead to creation of a database with thousands of default tables (of which I don't understand what they are).

Any method to create a blank database (no tables, no data) with this Oracle Database Configuration Assistant?

Comment: I suspect that the "thousands of default tables" are the system tables which Oracle uses to define everything else in the database. Generally these will be in the SYS schema, and should be left very much alone. Best of luck.

Comment: oh yeah, i authenticated as SYSTEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bob Jarvis noted in the comment area below the question. Those thousands of default tables appear because SYSTEM username is used when accessing the database.

It's impossible to create a totally-blank database (when being viewed as SYSTEM). Connect as SYSDBA and these default tables won't appear.